# Uniform convergence and improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I was thinking about this claim (Real analysis question)

let ${f_n}$ be a series of continuous functions that converges uniformly to $f(x)=0$ on the interval $[1,\infty)$  and that satisfies the following criteria $\forall  n\ge1 $ $\int_{1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left(x\right)dx\le1$.

then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}f_{n}\left(x\right)dx$= $0$.

I think this is false but I can't find a counter example. any Ideas on how to prove/disprove this?

Comment: I thought about the following counter example: let $f_n(x)= \frac{1}{n}$ on the interval $1 \le x\le n+1$ and 0 on the interval $x \gt n$. so then ${ f_n(x)}$ converges uniformly and satisfy the equality and the limit of the improper integral in respect to n over $f_n(x)$ is never 0. is this a good counter example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this converges. Your counterexample is correct. In that case, $f_n(x)\le1$, and it converges uniformly to $0$, but the limit of the integral is $1$ because the integral of each $f_n(x) = 1$.